# EC2 t2.micro instance not accessible over http/https

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created a new instance of EC2 instance t2.micro free tier Amazon Linux AMI in us-east-1 and used the default security group, subnet and vpc in us-east-1. I can ping the public IP and SSH successfully. However, I am not able to access the application over http/https. Connection could not established. I have attached required information as images. Could you spot anything which may cause this.

What I have done so far:

1. I have modified inbound rules on security group which allowed me to ping successfully.
2. Followed other similar posts on Stackoverflow.

[image: EC 2 Instance Details]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What application do you have running on port 80 and 443 on that instance?

Comment: Is the web server running? It is possible it is listening for local requests only, `netstat` output can give you a clue.

Comment: Its just a index.html page hosted on apache. I dont think the request is going all the way to web server.

Comment: Since you can SSH to the instance, network connectivity is fine. If the connection is rejected immediately, then it is being rejected by the app listening on the port. If it takes a while to be rejected, then either the Security Group is blocking the traffic (but your configuration looks fine) or an app isn't listening on that port. You should first test by connecting to the instance and trying `curl localhost` to see whether the web page appears. Then, from another instance in the same VPC, try it again, but specify the Private IP address of the instance (`curl 172.31.x.x`).

Comment: Thanks everyone for their suggestions. I did check the httpd service was running and curl localhost did return the web page. When I checked the instance today, the httpd service was stopped so I started it and guess what it worked. Don't know what happened there.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the httpd service on the EC2 intance did the trick.